# Java 8 Parse Day of the Week and Time

Tags: java, date, parsing, java-8

Here is a sample input from the user:

```
Wed 15:00
```

I want to parse this into an object so I'm using a `LocalDateTime` object. Here's my code:

```
String elem = "wed 15:00";
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "E H:mm"
            + "E HH:mm");
return LocalDateTime.from(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.parse(elem));
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'wed 15:00' could not be parsed at index 0
```

What exactly is the error here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a valid pattern:

```
"E H:mm" + "E HH:mm"
```

Try this instead:

```
String elem = "Wed 15:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E H:mm");
return LocalDateTime.from(LocalDate.parse(elem, formatter));
```

Also notice that you'll have to specify more than just the day of the week and time to parse a `LocalDateTime` object, it stands to reason: we don't know *what* Wednesday are we talking about!

Comment: then how do I handle parsing both `wed 1:00` and `wed 11:00`?

Comment: The code you posted is not valid to begin with. What _type_ exactly do you want to return?

Comment: I want to return a `LocalDateTime` object but I'm not sure that's the proper object to use. And I tried the above pattern and still got the same error

Comment: Notice that the string must be `Wed 15:00`, with a capital `W`. And I'm not quite sure _why_ you want to return a `LocalDateTime`...

Comment: ok `DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.parse(elem)` works but `LocalDateTime.from(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.parse(elem))` fails because `Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfWeek=3},ISO resolved to 15:00 of type java.time.format.Parsed`

Comment: You'll have to specify more than just the day of the week and time to parse a `LocalDateTime` object. I really, really think you have to go back to the drawing board and rethink what you're trying to accomplish, and whether `LocalDateTime` is the best data type for it.